# Castor OQLQuery: could not find engine for class

Tags: java, castor

I'm trying to execute a SQL query with Castor OQLQuery to retrieve datas from two differents table into on DTO object to send a JsonResponse later on.

I was able to write to correct query in SQL but the project I'm working on use **Castor v0.9.5.3** and I have to use the OQLQuery.

```java
    public static List<AvisOperationsDTO> findAvisOperationsFromCurLitLiaison(List<String> curLit, List<String> curLiaison) throws QueryException, DatabaseNotFoundException {
        List<AvisOperationsDTO> avisoperations = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("CALL SQL SELECT * FROM ( ");
        // SubQuery: Avis a partir du CUR LIT ou CUR LIAISON
        builder.append(" ( SELECT ll.LIAISONCUR AS \"curLiaison\", lit.LITCUR AS \"curLit\", lit.LITCODE AS \"ouvrageIdr\", lit.LITDESIGNATION AS \"ouvrageAdr\", ")
                .append("'avis' AS \"typeObjet\", avis.DATE_CREATION AS \"dateCreation\", avis.DESCRIPTION AS \"description\", avis.AVIS_ID AS \"identifiant\", ")
                .append("avis.STATUT AS \"statut\", compNature.LSTVALEUR AS \"equipement\", NULL AS \"debutPlanifie\" ")
                .append("FROM PLS_NAVIS avis ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LIAISONSOUTERRAINE ls ON ls.OUVR_ID = avis.OUVR_ID ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LIT lit ON lit.LITCODE = ls.LITCODE ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LIAISON_LIT ll ON ll.LITCUR = lit.LITCUR ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LISTE compNature ON avis.LST_ID_COMP_NATURE = compNature.LST_ID ")
                .append("WHERE avis.STATUT IN ('Créé', 'En surveillance') ")
                .append("AND avis.AVIS_ID NOT IN (SELECT op.AVIS_ID FROM PLS_OPERATION op WHERE op.AVIS_ID = avis.AVIS_ID) ")
                .append("AND ( lit.LITCUR IN ($1) OR ll.LIAISONCUR IN ($2) ) ");

        builder.append(" ) UNION ( ");

        //SubQuery: Avis à partir du CUR LIAISON
        builder.append("SELECT ll.LIAISONCUR AS \"curLiaison\", lit.LITCUR AS \"curLit\", lit.LITCODE AS \"ouvrageIdr\", lit.LITDESIGNATION AS \"ouvrageAdr\", ")
                .append("'opération' AS \"typeObjet\", op.DATE_CREATION AS \"dateCreation\", ")
                .append("CONCAT(CONCAT(nature.LSTVALEUR, ' - '), op.COMMENTAIRE) AS \"description\", op.OP_ID AS \"identifiant\", op.STATUT AS \"statut\", ")
                .append("CASE WHEN op.TYPE_OP = 'Conditionnelle' THEN ( ")
                    .append("SELECT compNature.LSTVALEUR FROM PLS_NAVIS avis ")
                    .append("JOIN PLS_LISTE compNature ON avis.LST_ID_COMP_NATURE = compNature.LST_ID ")
                    .append("WHERE op.AVIS_ID = avis.AVIS_ID ")
                .append(" ) ELSE ( ")
                    .append("SELECT eq.TYPE_EQ FROM PLS_OP_NAVIS_EQUIPEMENT eq WHERE eq.OPERATION_ID = op.OP_ID AND Rownum = 1 ")
                .append(") END AS \"equipement\", op.DATE_DEB_OP AS \"debutPlanifie\" ")
                .append("FROM PLS_OPERATION op ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LIAISONSOUTERRAINE ls ON ls.OUVR_ID = op.OUVR_ID ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LIT lit ON lit.LITCODE = ls.LITCODE ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LISTE nature ON op.LST_ID_NATURE = nature.LST_ID ")
                .append("JOIN PLS_LIAISON_LIT ll ON ll.LITCUR = lit.LITCUR ")
                .append("WHERE op.STATUT NOT IN ('EXEC', 'PEXE') ")
                .append("AND ( lit.LITCUR in ($3) OR ll.LIAISONCUR IN ($4) ) ");

        builder.append(" ) ORDER BY \"ouvrageIdr\") AS ")
                .append(AvisOperationsDTO.class.getName());

        StringJoiner joinerLit = new StringJoiner(",");
        StringJoiner joinerLiaison = new StringJoiner(",");
        try {
            Database db = CastorJDOFactory.getDatabase();
            db.begin();
            db.getQuery();

            OQLQuery query = db.getOQLQuery(builder.toString());
            QueryResults results = null;

            // .....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // .....
        }

        return avisoperations;
    }
```

But when I call `OQLQuery query = db.getOQLQuery(builder.toString());` Castor return this error:

> org.exolab.castor.jdo.QueryException: Could not find an engine supporting class com.rte.infocable.api.dto.AvisOperationsDTO

I've created a mapping xml file for my dto class:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE database PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor JDO Configuration DTD Version 1.0//EN" "/WEB-INF/mapping.dtd">

<mapping>
    <class name="com.rte.infocable.api.dto.AvisOperationsDTO" identity="identifiant">
        <description>AvisOperationDTO</description>
        <cache-type type="none"/>

        <field name="curLiaison" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="curLiaison" type="varchar" />
        </field>
        <field name="curLit" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="curLit" type="string" />
        </field>
        <field name="ouvrageIdr" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="ouvrageIdr" type="string" />
        </field><field name="ouvrageAdr" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="ouvrageAdr" type="string" />
        </field>
        <field name="typeObjet" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="typeObjet" type="string" />
        </field>
        <field name="dateCreation" type="java.time.LocalDateTime" required="true">
            <sql name="dateCreation" type="date" />
        </field>
        <field name="description" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="description" type="varchar" />
        </field>
        <field name="identifiant" type="integer" required="true">
            <sql name="identifiant" type="integer" />
        </field>
        <field name="statut" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="statut" type="varchar" />
        </field>
        <field name="equipement" type="string" required="true">
            <sql name="equipement" type="string" />
        </field>
        <field name="debutPlanifie" type="java.time.LocalDateTime" required="true">
            <sql name="debutPlanifie" type="Date" />
        </field>
    </class>
</mapping>
```

Then added this file in database.xml and databaseEchanges.xml as same as others xml mapping files used in the project:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE databases PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor JDO Configuration DTD Version 1.0//EN" "/WEB-INF/jdo-conf.dtd">
<database>
    <mapping href="classes/mapping/AvisOperationsDTO.xml"/>
</database>
```

I've tried reading a great part of the Castor doc and few SO posts but I couldn't find anyone with the same issue.

I'd like to be able to run my SQL Query through OQLQuery with Castor whatever the type it returns as far as I can do it in one query.

Note: it's not a viable solution for now to change the ORM nor upgrade Castor.

While debug with IntelliJ, I saw that Castor try to get the info type of my query through an attribut called `_typeInfo` (LockEngone.getClassMolder()::103) but this HashMap does not contain the type refering to my dto class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, I needed to add a `map-to` clause in the xml mapping file as follow:

```xml
<mapping>
    <class name="com.rte.infocable.api.dto.AvisOperationsDTO" identity="ouvrageIdr">
        <description>AvisOperationDTO</description>
        <cache-type type="none"/>
        <map-to table="PLS_NAVIS"/>
</mapping>
```

Event though my DTO class is not related to the oracle Table, it allow Castor to refer to the mapping file. With the use of `CALL SQL` Castor does not check if my `FROM` clause is similar to the map-to table name as the output fields are the same as I configure in the mapping file.